# Something wrong with JSPatch

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I don't know what's wrong with my code.When I clicked the button ,method does not perform.this is my code:

```
configView: function() {
    var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(0);
    button.setFrame({x:10,y:10,width:100,height:100});
    button.setTitle_forState('touch me',0);
    self.view().addSubView(button);
    button.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.redColor());
    button.setCenter(self.view().center());
    button.addTarget_action_forControlEvents(self,'touch',0);

},
touch:function(){
    console.log('touchme');
}
```

Could this be the issue?
`button.addTarget_action_forControlEvents(self,'touch',0)`

Comment: sorry,in my code ,`UIButtonTypeCustom UIControlStateNormal `is 0  like this `var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(0);
    button.setTitle_forState('touch me',0);`

Comment: What is your comment supposed to mean?

Comment: @Davesexcel the code I show you is wory,i am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Give Touchupinside as event so that it will work.

[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(touch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: button.addTarget_action_forControlEvents(self,'touch',6)

Comment: how do you add the method to button?

Comment: On storyboard u can give touchupinside as action and inside that u should write a fuction or action for it.for example in coding the above [button add target ....method is touch wch will be called.                                                                     @IBAction func settingsButtonClicked()
    {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SettingsPopOverTableViewControllerSegue", sender: self);
    }

Answer (score 0):

I got it by myself,the `UIControlEventTouchDown` type is `NS_OPTIONS`type`UIControlEventTouchDown                                         = 1 <<  0,`,so  the intValue of the type is 1,and i modify my code `button.addTarget_action_forControlEvents(self,'touch',1)`,it works will.